# Unable to translate "abusive or unkind comments" from the user flagged post page

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, offensive, automatic-flags

On the moderator page for user posts, the flag monitoring string *"{N} abusive or unkind comments in past {M} days, {username}"* is not ready to translation:

> [image]

Please add this string to translation engine.

Answer (score 4):

All done as of Aug 3, 2023. This is a translatable string now.